# Problem to get Context in FragmentView Kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, fragment

I need to get a Context from my activity. When i do that using:

```
   override fun getContext(): Context {

    return activity.applicationContext
}
```

i got:

safe ( .) or non-null asserted ( .) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type FragmentACtivity

Comment: `activity` is calling your fragment's `getActivity()` which isn't guaranteed to not be null. So you'll have to do `activity!!.applicationContext!!`

Comment: im calling this method from my Fragment... i think when that fragment are created, my activity is not null. Right?

Comment: There are scenarios in the life cycle of Android where the activity will be null during the instance of your Fragment. More often than not, activity will exist, but in this case Kotlin is forcing you to be smart about accessing it. A simple (but helpful) nuance of Kotlin

Comment: You are right man. Im newbie on Kotlin, i started on a few days ago. Thx dude.

Comment: No problem, a helpful approach to learning Kotlin in Android Studio is to click red errors (red squigglies under code) and use `ALT+ENTER` to get a solution to fix your problem - more often than not, it's Kotlin telling you to be hyper-conscious about nullability

Comment: Yeah i have been work on that. Thkssss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formality purposes, posting answer here

`activity` is calling your fragment's `getActivity()` which isn't guaranteed to not be null. So you'll have to do `activity!!.applicationContext!!`

There are scenarios in the life cycle of Android where the activity will be null during the instance of your Fragment. More often than not, activity will exist, but in this case Kotlin is forcing you to be smart about accessing it. A simple (but helpful) nuance of Kotlin

Comment: Is this the best we can do? Is there any other way to return a non null activity context? In my case I store the reference to a `val` in onCreate using `activity!!` then use that variable as my context reference.

Comment: Do like that and when activity will be null, you will have exception, as you said "There are scenarios in the life cycle of Android where the activity will be null during the instance of your Fragment" and then you call !! and get crash.

Better way is use injection of context, or view context if available.

Comment: @AntonKogan injecting context is generally bad context. The nullability of context has been a part of the platform since it's existence and it's on the developer to use it correctly. Hence why `requireActivity()` `requireApplication()` `requireContext()` was brought in.